# Instead of Enum

Tags: c#, enums

C# Enum Alternate

I'm not that much experience in C#,
I've a doubt, As we know that While coding we can able to select the Enum item from intellisense similar way instead of Enum any other possibility to get item from intellisense.

My requirement is I don't want Enum, I've Countries column in database table. I want to perform some validation on each Countries for example:

```
if( db.Countries.India )
{
   //some validation
}
```

Comment: you want to check if a column of your database has a value of `India` ?

Comment: Please stop using incorrect text formatting

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you need to do special things on certain records probably you are missing a column in database that indicates that the record is special. Hard coding stuff like ID or names are often bad database design

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what `db` is or why you don't want to use an `enum` (because you could perfectly do that, see below), but maybe this can help you:

```
public class Countries
{
    public const string India = "India";
    ...
}
```

or if you want the id of the country, you can use

```
public class Countries
{
    public const int India = 42;
    ...
}
```

Both of the proposed ways can be accessed like this:

```
var india = Countries.India;
```

---

I know this wasn't asked, but since the question indicates that the issue might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), here is what approach I recommend:

Let's say your country table looks like this:

```
CountryID | Name
------------------------------------
1         | India
42        | United States of America
```

then you could make an enum that looks like this:

```
public enum Country
{
    India = 1,

    [Description("United States of America")]
    United States = 42
}
```

and you don't lose any information whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

If you want intellisense to show you the *data* inside your colection, then it's not how it works. Your C# source code cannot use data in your DB, because data in your DB could change, while your code will stil reference some fixed name properties.

---

If you want intellisense to show you some available *functions* (extension functions) when you hit the dot key '.', then you have to include the namespace where these functions are defined in the beginning of your file, in order to let intellisense show the possibilities.

By far one of the most useful, especially to perform validation, would be to use :

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the beginning of your file

Then you could use something like this :

```
if (db.Countries.Any(c => c.Name == "India" ) {
     // this block will execute only if at least one country is India
}

foreach (var country in db.Countries.Where(c => c.Name == "India")) {
     // this block will execute for each element in countries that has Name equals India and attach the country to some variable so you can perform more work with it
}
```

---

If you want somehow to have a list of fixed values, like an enum, some interesting way is to use constants, this has been shown in Thomas' answer.

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was asking.

Comment: Let's wait for the OP's response.The questions seems illogical/incomplete and ....

Comment: @MickyD bad hit on touchscreen while typing some answer

Comment: haha no worries

Comment: @zackraiyan please stop commenting randomly on posts.  This isn't a forum.  Flag questions instead

Comment: @zackraiyan you are allowed to, but please *ask the OP* instead of us then. Why should we know more than the OP?

Comment: @zackraiyan flagged

Answer (score 1):

> I want to perform some validation on each Countries for example

You must looping all the countries in the database, which is not shown in your snippet. If your validation is only for few countries and not all, you can use switch statement.

**Important:** `Enum` will only create maintainability issues. What if tomorrow you decided to remove "India" from Db, you also have to update your enums.

```
foreach (var country in db.Countries)
{
     switch(country.Name)
     {
          case "India": 
               // do my stuff when country is India
          break;
          case "Singapore": 
               // do my stuff when country is Singapore
          break;
          default:
              // default operation for other countries.
          break;
     }
}
```

**As an alternate**, you can run a pre-build script to generate your enum class from Db. That can help you overcome maintainability issue, but still the above loop will remain.

Comment: *"Enum will only create maintainability issues. [If] [...] you [...] remove 'India' from Db, you also have to update your enums"* - not sure if I get your point; if you remove a value from the database, you need to update the representation in code as well, regardless of whether you're using enums or whatever. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, it can also be other way round, what if you add new countries to db, you have to add them to `Enum` too. Why I said remove is because that particular enum value when removed from database table is no longer any importance in the code.

Comment: you're right, let me rephrase it: you say that *only when using enums* you have to update them when you update the table in the database, don't you?

Answer (score -2):

Try this working:

```
if(db.Countries.ToList().Any(t=>t.country=="India"))
```

Comment: How does this even answer OP's question?

Comment: Say some thing about your answer how it address op's question ? .Code only answer and try this is not good way to answer.